# Double click on mobile as replacement for hover effect

Tags: javascript, css

I have a boxes on my website with a hover animation similar to what you see below.

I was wondering if I could achieve this effect, or something like it on the first click on mobile and the second click will take the user to the destination of the a-tag.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.ptahai.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Best-Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you consider a compromise? How about showing half the overlay on small screens. example --> resize the viewport https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/tnvw1ovd/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help you, call the CSS class when you click, and the double click to call the destination

```
<a href="#">
<div  id="container" onclick="first()" ondbclick="doble()">
<img src="http://www.ptahai.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Best-Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="text">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function first(){
document.getElementById("container").className = "overlay";} 

function doble(){
alert("here the href")}
```